# How to successfully set up both the html templace and view for Recaptcha v2 without using forms

Tags: python-3.x, django, recaptcha

I read other related questions about recaptcha and django without forms but I didn't find a complete solution or the posts where too old.

My situation is this:

I am using the package django-recaptcha. I added the "captcha" app in INSTALLED_APPS and setted up the private and public keys for recaptcha.

This is currently my code in views:

```
def verify_recaptcha(response):
    url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify'
    params = {
        'secret': settings.RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY,
        'response': response,
    }
    response = requests.post(url, data=params)
    data = response.json()
    return data['success']


def contact(request):
    context = {
        'RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY': settings.RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY
    }
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        message = request.POST.get('message')
        captcha_response = request.POST.get('recaptcha_response')

        if name and email and message:
            if verify_recaptcha(captcha_response):
                send_mail(
                    subject="Contact Form Submission",
                    message=f"""
                    Name: {name}
                    Email: {email}
                    Message: {message}
                    """,
                    from_email=FROM_EMAIL,
                    recipient_list=[TO_EMAIL],
                    fail_silently=False,
                )
                context['message'] = 'Your message has been sent!'
            else:
                context['error'] = 'Invalid reCAPTCHA response.'
        else:
            context['error'] = 'Please fill in all required fields.'
    return render(request, 'contact.html', context)
```

And this is the extract of my html template:

```
<div class="field">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="{{ RECAPTCHA_PUBLIC_KEY }}"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response">
</div>
    <div class="field has-text-centered">
    <button type="submit" class="button is-success has-background-success-dark"> Submit </button>
</div>
```

I am using the recaptcha v2. The widget seems to work just fine in the website, but it fails to validate the recaptcha.

I am still in the development environment, and I made sure to add the 127.0.0.1 domain in my registered recaptcha.

I also rechecked the keys several times and my Content Security Policy but everything seems file. I just saw this warning: "Partitioned cookie or storage access was provided to “https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?(...)” because it is loaded in the third-party context and dynamic state partitioning is enabled". But I don't know if it's related.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Thanks!